# Вывод структуры в файл

Tags: c++

код:

```
  std::cout << "enter file to write\n> ";
  std::string filename;
  std::cin >> filename;
  std::ofstream myfile(filename, std::ofstream::app | std::ofstream::binary);
  if (myfile){
    std::streamsize size = sizeof(city);
    myfile.write(temp, size);
    std::cout << "SAVED!\n";
  }
  myfile.close();
```

поля структуры city:

```
struct city
{
    char name[32];
    int citizens;
    float territory;
    int startyear;
    int schools;
};
```

ошибка:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:61:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(city&, std::streamsize&)’
             myfile.write(temp, size);
                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:693:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/ostream.tcc:182:5: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::write(const _CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::streamsize = long int]
     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/ostream.tcc:182:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘city’ to ‘const char*’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае важны не поля структуры, а что вы передаете. Подозреваю, что `tmp` - **не адрес** объекта `city`, а ссылка на него.

В то время как функция ожидает указателя на `char`.

Comment: я хочу записать структуру в файл.

Comment: temp - это у меня экземпляр структуры city

Comment: как экземпляр структуры сделать строкой? (char*)temp не прокатило xD

Comment: Передавайте `(char*)&temp`. И это - **не** строка, это - адрес, откуда брать записываемые данные. И сразу, чтоб не было неожиданностью - если вы в будущем замените, например, `char name[32];` на `string name;` - то такая запись в файл станет сразу неверной.

Comment: а, понял. чтобы записать структуру в файл мне надо передать методу write символьный указатель на адрес начала экземпляра структуры и собственно размер структуры. так?

Comment: а можно тогда сразу поинтересоваться как прочитать структуру из файла? всмысле методом read я ведь получу строку. а как из неё обратно сделать объект структуры? или надо читать каждое из полей отдельно и записывать в новый объект?

Comment: @КолянИванцов Про чтение новый  вопрос создайте

Comment: Да точно так же! `.read((char*)&temp,size)`